# Scala, list append don't work inside recursive function

Tags: scala, recursion

So I was working on algorithm that would take a binary tree:

```
sealed trait BT
case object Empty extends BT
case class Node(val x: Int, val left: BT, val right: BT) extends BT
```

and return binary tree but without duplicates with help of recursive dfs to search the tree.

```
  def removeRecurring_dfs(bt: BT, found: List[Int]): BT = {
    def dfs_helper(tree: BT): BT = {
      tree match
        case Empty => Empty
        case Node(x, _, _) if found.contains(x) => dfs_helper(rR(tree))
        case Node(x, Empty, Empty) =>
          x::found
          tree
        case Node(x, left, Empty) =>
          x::found
          Node(x, dfs_helper(left), Empty)
        case Node(x, Empty, right) =>
          x::found
          Node(x, Empty, dfs_helper(right))
        case Node(x, left, right) =>
          x::found
          Node(x, dfs_helper(left), dfs_helper(right))
    }
    def rR(tree: BT): BT = removeNode(tree, findPath(tree))
    dfs_helper(bt)
  }
```

List 'found' is initially empty. 'removeNode' and 'findPath' are functions that help me achieve my goal. After some testing I found out that

```
x::found
```

line never works, even when case with that line is triggered. With some println action it turned out that pattern matching works as I intented.

I have started playing with scala recently and i don't understand what could cause such behavior

Comment: Well, it may help if before trying to write a binary tree, you first write a `List`, and immutable one. That way you will see why `x :: found` did work, it creates a NEW list, because you know, the idea of something immutable is that it doesn't mutate. - Anyways, you may add an additional parameter to your search algorithm or you could use a mutable collection or a `var` - As I said, if you are new to the language, you should star with something simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been pointed out, `List` is immutable so `x :: found` creates a new `List` with the element `x` prepended to the `found` list.

The new `List` has to be saved/sent somewhere, otherwise it is lost and garbage collected.

I don't know what your `findPath()` and `removeNode()` methods are supposed to do, so it's a bit hard to say, but it looks like this is what you're trying to accomplish. (Scala-3 syntax)

```
sealed trait BT
case object Empty extends BT
case class Node(x: Int, left: BT, right: BT) extends BT

def removeRecurring_dfs(bt: BT): BT =
  def dfs_helper(tree:BT, found:Set[Int]): (BT,Set[Int]) = tree match
    case Empty => (Empty, found)
    case Node(x, left, right) =>
      if found(x) then
        dfs_helper(rR(tree), found)
      else
        val (lftNode, moreFound)  = dfs_helper(left, found + x)
        val (rgtNode, totalFound) = dfs_helper(right, moreFound)
        (Node(x, lftNode, rgtNode), totalFound)

  def rR(tree: BT): BT = removeNode(tree, findPath(tree))
  dfs_helper(bt, Set())._1
```